# How to trigger a kubernetes/openshift job restart when ever a specific pod in the cluster will restart?

Tags: kubernetes

For example, I have a pod running a server in it and I have a job in my cluster that is doing some yaml patching on the server deployment.

Is there a way we can set up some kind of trigger or anything that will rerun the job when ever the respective deployment change happens?

Comment: Can you please provide some details regarding your job? If it needs to do something at the pod start only, you can look for the K8s initcontainers.

Comment: job should add a patch yaml to a specific deployment yaml . 
So the job should start after the pod for the above deployment is up.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your job spec into the deployment as `initContainer` like that:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: example
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init
        image: centos:7
        command:
        - "bin/bash"
        - "-c"
        - "do something useful"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
```

In this case every time you rollout the deployment, job defined in `initContainers` will run.